# Mutiple fetches on GAE causing invalid handle

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm having trouble with GAE when doing several **SYNCHRONOUS** requests with the same query parameters.

My query:

```
Query<Movimentacao> q = ofy().query(Movimentacao.class).ancestor(ANCESTOR_KEY);
        q.filter("codStatus =", MyEnum.ENVIADO);
        q = q.order("datMovRegistrada").limit(1);
        return q.get();
```

After some calls I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid handle: 5736689025196469674
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$AsyncCallWrapper.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:35)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.getIndexList(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.loadMoreEntities(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:181)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.loadMoreEntities(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.hasNext(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:64)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingIterator.hasNext(TranslatingIterator.java:29)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:389)
    at br.com.sulamerica.susis.mecsas.web.model.repositorio.MovimentacaoRepositoryImpl.getMovimentacaoSincronia(MovimentacaoRepositoryImpl.java:153)
    at br.com.sulamerica.susis.mecsas.web.service.ManutencaoMovimentacaoServiceImpl.retornaMovimentacaoFila(ManutencaoMovimentacaoServiceImpl.java:1532)
    at br.com.sulamerica.susis.mecsas.web.controller.TaskQueueController.recuperaMovimentacao(TaskQueueController.java:126)
```

Aby thoughts why this is happening ?

I'm using Objectify 3.1.

Thanks !

Comment: The only reference to this type of issue I can find seems to be an old transient issue reported on the GAE issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8589. Perhaps another transient issue?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The URL provided isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "invalid handle" means, but I do notice that the `q.filter(...)` in your posted code is not an assignment. It needs to be `q = q.filter(...)` like the others.

I can't tell if this is a typo or a real issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue (if it makes a difference) but I assing the q to `q = q.order("datMovRegistrada").limit(1);`. Isn't it right or the same as doing `q = q filter(...)` ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking here. I'm just pointing out that you have a line in your code which does not assign `q`; this line is a no-op and has no effect on the program result. The `filter` method does not mutate a query, but only returns a query with the specified filter.